# Exposed grouped filters - inputs on a date field don't render

Tags: views, datetime

I am having the same issue as listed here:https://www.drupal.org/node/2128683

I am using:

- Latest version of Drupal core
- Views 7.x-3.10
- jQuery 1.7
- Use AJAX is enabled on the view

If I do not group the the filter the "select a date" and "enter a relative date" display their respective input fields.
Once I select **Grouped filters** neither "select a date" or "enter a relative date" display the input field.

Any help would be appreciated.